# Postfix: How to accept email with valid SPF but unresolvable hostname?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, spam, spf

I have configured my Postfix to reject email sent from hosts without PTR record and hostnames that don't have A record. I found there are legitimate mail servers with valid SPF records which don't have A record for their hostname. As a result the legitimate emails were rejected.

Is there a way to configure Postfix to accept email with valid SPF record even if there's no A record for the hostname or there's no PTR record for the IP address?

Comment: You mean is there a way to remove the configuration you already put in?

Comment: @84104 I mean I want postfix to first check SPF record, if SPF pass, accept email, don't check PTR or A record. If no SPF record, then check  PTR record and A record. If no PTR record or A record, reject the email.

Comment: SPF alone is not a panacea when it comes to filtering out spam. It helps to protect against address spoofing, but not spam.

Answer (score 8):

This could be possible if `check_policy_service` responded `permit` (from [`access(5)`](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) other actions) instead of neutral accept action `OK` vs. reject action `reject`. That would need modification to the SPF policy service [`policyd-spf.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf.5.en.html). Although I have never actually tried this, based on the manpage it seems that `Pass` condition for both `HELO` and `MAIL FROM` allows using ANY action defined in [`access(5)`](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html). Resulting configuratoin parameters in `policyd-spf.conf`:

```
HELO_pass_restriction = permit
Mail_From_pass_restriction = permit
```

Now, the order of the restrictions starts to matter as SPF policy service answers:

- `reject` on SPF `Fail`
- `permit` on SPF `Pass`
- neutral `OK` on all other conditions including errors, `Softfail`, `Neutral` and no SPF.

Then, the Postfix `main.cf` can have all your restrictions in this kind of order:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,

    [checks done regardless of SPF],

    check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf,

    [checks done only if SPF didn't either Pass or Fail],

    permit
```

Both `permit` and `reject` are first matches mentioned in [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions)

> Restrictions are applied in the order as specified; the first restriction that matches wins

while the neutral response from any restriction causes moving to the next one.

Comment: I've never tried this because my preferred order wouldn't make sense with direct `permit` on SPF `Pass`. My order: 1) Generic tests. 2) Local access lists. 3) SPF 4) hand picked RBLs, widest first. This way I can limit unnecessary RBL checks.

Answer (score 4):

Quote [from the Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions):

> Restrictions are applied in the order as specified; the first restriction that matches wins

So no, it's not possible. If only one of the restrictions matches it results in the mail being rejected, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: That's with `policyd-spf` default configuration: you can't do this with Postfix configuration alone. However, see from my answer how this might be possible by modifying `policyd-spf.conf`.